# Wait for the response from another component in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have a created a component called popupmessage to show custom message with "ok" and "cancel" button. This i am invoking from another component say component "a" using `$compile` like below.

a.js has the below code to invoke popupmessagebox:

```
var dialogBox = $compile('<pop-up-message id="messagebox" message="' + response.data + '" okbutton="' + "true" + '"cancelbutton="' + "false"'"></pop-up-message>')($scope);
$('.data-table').append(dialogBox);
```

After this i want to reload component "a" on clicking of OK button in popupmessage component. How do i do this?
Reloading of component "a" can be achieved by adding `window.location.reload()` after the above lines.
but it does not wait until i click "OK" in popupmessage component.

I want to call reload in "a" component after clicking of button "ok" in popupmessage component.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Q: Are people still using AngularJS?

Comment: @FoggyDay, sorry but irrelevant comment..

Comment: Clearly the OP is "just learning".  Perhaps he picked up an old tutorial somwhere, and doesn't realize that AngularJS is no longer actively being maintained?  That Angular might be a better choice?

Comment: I'm not sure how you get that `OP is just learning` but NM. You get my point. Take it or leave it.

Comment: I'm curious: Q: Why would anyone choose to write new applications using AngularJS (long since deprecated, no longer maintained, with obsolete constructs like "$scope") vs. a newer version of Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how `pop-up-message` directive looks like but I guess it's somehow similar to the code below.

Anyway, directive can receive data from whom call it via its attribute, but you already know this because you pass the `message` for example, to the directive.

Directive can receive also functions. So you declare the function in the controller / component, pass it via the attributes, and then you can call it in the directive.

Even if your controller / directive are not looking the same as the example <sup>[1]</sup>, you probably can get the idea of how to implement it.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.show = function() {
      // fake response
      const response = {
        data: 'my data'
      }
      $scope.modalCallback = function() {
        console.log('callback fired');
        // window.location.reload() <-- now you can call it
      }

      var dialogBox = $compile('<pop-up-message id="messagebox" message="' + response.data + '" okbutton="true" cancelbutton="false" callback="modalCallback()"></pop-up-message>')($scope);
$('.data-table').append(dialogBox);
    }
  })
  .directive('popUpMessage', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        message: '@',
        callback: '&'
      },
      template: `
        <div>
          {{message}}
          <button ng-click="callback()">Ok</button>
        </div>
      `
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-click="show()">show modal</button>
</div>

<div class="data-table"></div>
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> In the example I used [isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive). If your directive is not using it, you should declare the `callback` function on the `scope` you're passing the directive and it should work the same.